# port 80 closing continuously

Tags: iis, port

I am new to iis and i am hosting a site which i can access via `http://localhost`. Few days earlier i changed the website's binding to my internal ip. And after forwarding port 80, i was able to access it via my external ip. I checked my port on `www.yougetsignal.com` and `wwww.canyouseeme.org`. Both showed a green flag that is, my port 80 is open. But yesterday, suddenly i was not able to access my website. I checked the port again on the same websites and got the result that my ports are NOT open. How is it possible? i opened up my ports but suddenly then were closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding on your internal ip, are you allocating a static internal ip? If not then your ip address may have changed. So either update the binding to use * (All Unassigned) or allocate a static internal ip from your router that matches the binding ip.